# How to make Non Removable Footer Credit

Tags: jquery, html, css

I add a HTML footer like :

```
<footer id='copyright'>
        <p>Copyright 2014</p>
        </a>Designed by XYZ</a>
</footer>
```

Now, I need your help. It is that the users use my theme cannot remove footer.

It means the users cannot:

- Add display:none; visibility:hidden or the same actions.
- Remove it from code.

(cannot hide or remove)

How jQuery can do it? (I will encrypt jQuery code)

Thank for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent that.

Comment: You cannot protect your html in such a way.

Comment: A nasty and not a recommended solution would be to set an interval in which you run a javascript function. Every time you check if your footer is in place, if not, you append it from js. :))

Comment: Hi. In encrypted jquery code have some code that is related to action of many elements.

Comment: There is no such thing as encrypted jQuery code. It may be obfusticated, but this won't stop any attacker with enough time and/or energy.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Even that wouldn't help too much if I write my own code to move the copyright notice off-screen, then bind an event to listen to DOM changes to detect if it gets moved back, and remove it again. It's ridiculous, of course (I'd rather just make my own stuff) but Scimonster is right.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol haha, it's ridiculous, indeed... It was just a funny  instant ideea. Same way I could listen to DOM changes and whenever gets out I'd put it back in. But to sum up, I think the answer to this OP is that you can't prevent that. +1 for Scimonster

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Ooh, just found a way to win. Create an element of my own and use `position` and `z-index` to place it on top of the copyright notice. Good luck detecting that :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol hehe, I'd cycle through every element that has position and z-index, I'd get the greatest z-index and then I'd set on my element a z-index + 1 value :)) But I think we should stop playing with all these nasty ideas, we don't want DOM to bleed or explode, right? :-D

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Or I just remove your javascript code... ;)

Comment: Or... you could refresh your site every several seconds! :))

Answer (score 2):

Basically you cannot do this. There's no way of protecting it completely.